# Convert query from sql to hql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql

i want to convert this query to HQL

```
select status,count(*) from server s, status st where s.id = st.server_id and st.created = (select max(ss.created) from status ss where ss.server_id = s.id) group by st.status
```

i tried this

```
@Query("select new StatisticServerDTO( st.status, count(*)) from Server s, Status st where "
            + "s.id = st.server.id and st.created = (select max(ss.created) from Status ss where ss.server.id = s.id)"
            + "group by st.status")
    List<StatisticServerDTO> nbrServerByStatus();
```

but its not working

my return class is like :

```
public class StatisticServerDTO{

    private String status;
    private int nbr;

   ...
}
```

the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'StatisticServerDTO' {originalText=StatisticServerDTO}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'status1_.status' {propertyName=status,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=status,path=st.status,tableAlias=status1_,className=com.example.beans.Status,classAlias=st}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'status1_.id' {alias=st, className=com.example.beans.Status, tableAlias=status1_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'status' {originalText=status}
       \-[COUNT] CountNode: 'count'
          \-[ROW_STAR] SqlNode: '*'
```

Comment: show your exception trace..

Comment: @mhasan i added the Exceptioins

Comment: I think you need to specify the full package in the query. `select new com.mypackage.StatisticServerDTO(...`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing New in your query

@Query("select **NEW** StatisticServerDTO( st.status, count(*)) from Server s, Status st where "
            + "s.id = st.server.id and st.created = (select max(ss.created) from Status ss where ss.server.id = s.id)"
            + "group by st.status")
    List nbrServerByStatus();

Comment: i add it but nothing change

Comment: Do you have same constructor in your DAO  like Public StatisticServerDTO(String status, int count){this.status=status;this.nbr= count} and also check you also must have no Argument constructor in your class

Comment: Yes i have all this

Comment: this may have caused because of count(*) , instead of counting * try to use a specific column from a table.